# Remove all "-" inside select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in wordpress a list of options, but it generates with sub level menu's automatic a - before it. Now I wanna loop them out but can't get it seems to work.

I targeted my menu items and try to loop out the "-" to remove them.

```
var $menuitem = $(".hasCustomSelect .menu-item");

$menuitem.filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) ==  '-'
}).remove();
```

small codepen

http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/NGGrgR

Comment: It's because trim only removes whitespace. You can't make trim remove other characters. You need different tool for this, e.g. `regex`.

Comment: Never heard of it, gonna give it a look.

Comment: What should happen to the entries that are just a single `-`? Like between 9.5 and 10? Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/acfsnmn1/?

Comment: Exacly what i'm after, well that was a part after than I found the solution of this problem, it should just simply remove the element when it has a single -. If you have an idea

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly. The problem is you are trying to match the wrong kind of dash `-` vs `—`. Try this instead `return $.trim($(this).text()) == '—';`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNLZyv

Answer (score 0):

I can see a - vs a —, Try copy paste from the codepen or from below code

Also I guess you want to use

```
var $menuitem = $(".hasCustomSelect .menu-item");

$menuitem.filter(function(){
   return $.trim($(this).text()).indexOf('—')>-1;//all values containing `—`
}).remove();
```

Or if you really want to delete only the single - than

```
return $.trim($(this).text())=='—'; //the value that is `—`
```

Updated Code Pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKMeJv

Comment: If I combine the code to also remove the short dashes it doesn't work. This only removes the spaces in between.

Answer (score 0):

If removing the separator options, is what you wanted, then imtheman has a [solution for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32573630/1598508).

If you wanted to remove the leading dashes from the menu captions (my first guess on what you need), then you can go with the snippet below:

```
var $menuitem = $(".hasCustomSelect .menu-item");
$.each($menuitem, function(key, val){
    $(val).text($(val).text().replace(/—+ /,''));
});
```